# Can we increase the memory limit of PHP directly from the command line?

Tags: command-line, apache2, php, ram, 18.10

Can we increase the memory limit of PHP directly from the command line?

I am having more than one PHP installation on my ubuntu system and I am using a simple [php-switch-scripts](https://github.com/itsdanielfelix/php-switch-scripts) script to setup and switch between the PHP versions.

But I often run into a situation where I face some issues with the php.ini config values.

for example, I would have updated my **memory_limit** value to some higher value on my **php.ini** that is for PHP 7.2 but might not increased it on the php.ini of PHP 7.4.

Yes, I do understand that I could have updated the values in all of my php.ini files in less time than I took to write to this question but **if there is a way I can automate this using a shell script** I want to do it. so that both I and my colleagues make use of it in the future.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Ubuntu 18.10 is EOL (*end-of-life*) thus off-topic on this site (refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic). Being EOL, mirrors can drop the release, and the main archive moves to old-releases.  Refer https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades  http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/07/19/ubuntu-18-10-cosmic-cuttlefish-end-of-life-reached-on-july-18-2019/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do just about anything from the command line if you're *really* invested in solving the problem. For what you want to do, though, a couple of simple commands can help you accomplish the goal: `grep`, `sed`, and *ideally* `cp`.

To see the current value of something, use `grep`:

```
grep '^memory_limit ' /etc/php/7.4/apache2/php.ini
```

Be sure to replace `7.4` with whatever version you want to view at the time.

To replace an existing value, use `sed`:

```
sed -i 's,^memory_limit =.*$,memory_limit = 8192M,' /etc/php/7.4/apache2/php.ini
```

Again, replace `7.4` with the version you want to update and the absurd `8192M` bit with the actual value you want to set.

Once this is done, restart Apache with:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

You now have all the basic elements required to write a custom script to accomplish your goal and, perhaps, go a little further by making it work with any valid setting. For example:

```
./setPHPvariable 7.4 memory_limit 128M
./setPHPvariable 7.2 max_execution_time 300
```

Note that it's a good idea to create a backup of the `php.ini` file before making changes. This is where `cp` is your friend.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable inputs @Matigo